# Storing variables in loop and passing it to controller

Tags: php, arrays, loops, model-view-controller

Here is my code/layout:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $username = $row['username'];
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
}
```

as you can see, i am looping through my "users" database table and there are thousands users.

How can i store the information and pass it to my controller to display the information?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `while` loop, you can fetch them all into an array using the [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But are you really fetching your entire users table? It seems like a lot of work for your application to do. Normally for something like an index (for example) you would use pagination so you wouldn't have to fetch thousands of rows for each request.

Comment: yes ur right. not sure how to do pagination right now so i am doing this to learn. whats the difference between `fetchAll` and Nate's answer to put everything into array after it fetches?

Comment: It's the same effect. `fetchAll` is just a shortcut method.

Comment: ok, thank you. in a scenario where performance and speed matter (like a social network), what would be the fastest and most efficeint way?

Comment: I think the `fetchAll` might be a little faster than fetching single rows into an array in a loop, although I haven't tested it. But if you're executing the same query and fetching the same records, the difference will be negligible. Selecting a reasonably sized set of records, optimizing your queries, and adding appropriate indexes will make much more of a difference in performance than which fetch method you choose.

Answer (score 3):

It's tough to answer this question without knowing the specific problem you're facing.  But if you're seeking basic guidance re: model-view-controller, this extremely-simplified class outline might offer some guidance:

```
class MyModel
{
    public function getData()
    {
        $toReturn = array();

        // Prepare & execute your SQL statement.

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $toReturn[] = array(
                $row['username'],
                $row['first_name'],
                $row['last_name']
            );
        }
        return $toReturn;
    }
}

class MyController
{
    public function indexAction() 
    {
        $model = new MyModel();

        // Retrieve the data from the model.
        $dataForView = $model->getData();

        // Send the data to the view so it can be displayed.
        $this->render($dataForView);
    }
}
```